# How can I perform calculation in Javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery

I have 2 tables in a class:

```
public class Table1 {
    public string Name{set;get;}
    public string Price{set;get;}
}
public class Table2 {
    public string Name{set;get;}
    public string Price{set;get;}
}
```

I have two input fields, one have name from table1 and another name from table2, based on whatever Name a user selects from both tables. Jquery should add price based on two of the selected names.

```
$(document).on("click", "#buttonClick", function () {
    for (var price in data) {
        if () {

        }
    }
});
```

Question: how can i pass table1 Name and Price to jquery. When i click `#buttonClick` it should calculate price. For example:

```
Table1
Name       Price
RoomA      $22 
RoomB      $23

Table2
Name       Price
BuildingA  $33
BuildingB  $30
```

If i select RoomA from field1(Table1) and BuildingA from field2(Table2) then i should get output as $55. So how can i pass Name and Price from Table1 and Table2 to jquery.
I am getting Name and Price from database.

Comment: Post your generated (by ASP server i presume) HTML

Comment: i am using SQL server management studio- the post should add the calculation in asp.net field. - is this what you mean?

Comment: jQuery works with HTML. Are you sure you want to perform calculations using jQuery?

Comment: yes-is there any alternative ways to accomplish this? i can use ASP.net, Jquery or C#. My website is based on jquery so it would be grate to use jQuery- but as long as it works i can go with anything. What would be the best way to accomplish this?

Comment: Try [**this**](http://jsfiddle.net/n1k1ch/5Dxyf/) fiddle. There is a pure jQuery/JavaScript way to calculate based on your requirements. I can post it as an answer with explanations if you like

Comment: @n1k1ch grate this is what i was looking for. Just one more question instead of table how do i make it dropdown menu - so dropbox1 should have name for Rooms and dropbox2 will have BuildingNames(Rooms & Buildings price should be hidden from users). How do i fire a onselect event instead onclick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, for two dropdowns (`select`s) described in following html:

```
<select id="roomz">
    <option value="0">Select a room...</option>
    <option value="22">Room A</option>
    <option value="23">Room B</option>
</select>
<select id="buildingz">
    <option value="0">Select a building...</option>
    <option value="22">Building A</option>
    <option value="23">Building B</option>
</select>
```

(`value` of each `option` should be the actual price),

you can listen for [`change`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/change) event, get `value`s of each `select`, sum them and put result wherever you need (for example, to some `<input id="result" type="text" />`.

## JavaScript:

```
function calculate() {
    //get selected values
    var roomPrice = $("#roomz").val();
    var buildingPrice = $("#buildingz").val();

    //get sum of values
    var result = parseFloat(roomPrice) + parseFloat(buildingPrice);

    //put sum to result
    $("#result").val(result);//or val("$" + result) if you want to display dollar sign
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    //listen to 'change' event of several selects
    $(document).on("change", "#roomz,#buildingz", function (e) {
        calculate();
    });
});
```

## Here is the [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/n1k1ch/WY3A4/)